# Creating a method which insures assignment to another Model in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a model creating my `Country` table

```
var Country = db.define(
  'country',
  {
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    GFI: {
      type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
      validate: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
      },
    },
    flagUrl: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom.svg',
    },
  },
  {}
);
```

And a Model which makes defines 'Airplanes'

```
var Country = require('./country');
var Aircraft = db.define(
  'aircraft',
  {
    make: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    model: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    year: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      validate: {
        isAfter: '1903-12-31',
      },
    },
    type: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      validate: {
        isIn: ['Attack', 'Bomber', 'Versatile', 'Transport', 'Reconoissance', 'Rescue'],
      },
    },
    cost: {
      type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(7, 2),
    },
    imageUrl: {
      defaultValue:
        'http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/the-wright-brothers-give-a-demonstration-of-their-wright-model-a-picture-id530836658?k=6&m=530836658&s=612x612&w=0&h=66RNNerGkWA4C_784UK1-bXRret0CHY8QDl_HRYSY6I=',
    },
    description: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
    },
  },
  {}
);
```

I have created the associations like this:

```
Aircraft.belongsTo(Country);
Country.hasMany(Aircraft);
```

My aircraft must be assigned to a country on creation.

I know a hook might be appropriate:

```
Aircraft.hook('beforeCreate', aircraft => {
  aircraft.Country.name;
});
```

But I am not really sure, any help will be appreciated!